# Django ClassBasedViews - Generic Views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I get a strange Error: 'ListView' must define 'queryset' or 'model'

Here is my ListView:

```
class ProjectListView(ListView):
    template_name = "ProjectList.html"
    model = Project
    context_object_name = "projects"
```

I have the same problem with a CreateView. Is there any other information need to find a solution?

How to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

You must define a `get_queryset()` function in each generic `ListView` view.
That's how you tell django what objects you want to display.

`Model` is **NOT** your project. It must be set to a model class.
Say, you have a model called `Poll` in your `models.py` file. And you want to display all polls in the db, using the generic ListView. Then you could write this:

```
model = Poll
```

That equals to this query:

```
Poll.objects.all()
```

If you want to override this and show objects e.g. with publication date during the last week, then you define a `get_queryset()` with nedeed query parameters:

```
ProjectListView(generic.ListView):
    # ...
    def get_queryset(self):
       return obj.objects.filter(pub_date__gte=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7))
```

And so on.

Comment: I have "project" defined in my Models.py

Comment: @spitzbuaamy is this exactly this code you have in your IDE? Any typos?

Comment: from django.views.generic import CreateView, ListView
from Projects.models import Project
from Projects.forms import ProjectForm


class ProjectListView(ListView):
    template_name = "ProjectList.html"
    model = Project
    context_object_name = "projects"

class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Project
    template_name = "ProjectCreate.html"
    context_object_name = 'projects'
    form_class = ProjectForm